# stop and delete running containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I installed from here a simple training application `https://github.com/dockersamples/example-voting-app`

After that i want to remove working containers and then images of this app. I`m trying type this:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm -f *containers*
```

First everything is deleted, but then the containers are restarted and recreated automatically even though I deleted this folder from the computer with the application.
And have this error
 `Error response from daemon: You cannot remove a running container`

Probably autostart is registered in `docker-compose-files`, but I already deleted the folder with this project from my mac

Every time i have 3 this running containers :

```
dockersamples/visualizer:stable                "npm start" vote_vis
dockersamples/examplevotingapp_result:before   "node server.vote_res
postgres:9.4                                   "docker-entry vote_db.
```

How can i fix it and delete everything?

Comment: Have you tried forced `rm` with `-f`?  Have you looked at the restart policy for your containers with `docker container inspect $(docker ps -aq) | grep -A 3 RestartPolicy`?

Comment: I tried `docker rm -f *containers*` but then they are recreated too.  In `RestartPolicy` i see 3 identical blocks `"RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },`, what's next?

Comment: Just do `docker-compose down && docker-compose rm -f -v`.

Comment: @Strelok I deleted my directory and have this :-( `Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent` is there another way?:-(

Comment: Stop your Docker daemon, and then delete your /var/lib/docker/ data ?

Comment: I mean personally my first instinct will be to put the folder back if you’re having trouble. Not sure what you’re doing wrong before because `docker rm -f` should have been enough in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have the containers running in swarm mode. When you stop or delete a container, swarm mode will see the difference from the target state and redeploy containers to get you to the target state. To stop and delete containers started by swarm mode, you need to run stack and service commands instead:

```
docker stack rm $(docker stack ls --format '{{.Name}}')
```

Give that a minute to complete, then for any services not managed as a stack, you can run:

```
docker service rm $(docker service ls -q)
```